# proper way to write Java bean getter/setter method when first word is only 1 letter long

Tags: java, javabeans

Just read the Java Bean spec 1.01 which includes the [`decapitalize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize(java.lang.String)) function which states:

> Utility method to take a string and convert it to normal Java variable name capitalization. This normally means converting
>   the first character from upper case to lower case, but in the (unusual) special case when there is more than one
>   character and both the first and second characters are upper case, we leave it alone.

So if I want to write a getter for a Java Bean property named `qValue`, does that mean I should use `getqValue()` rather than `getQValue()`?

Comment: interesting: I've been programming in Java for 6 years and I never ran into this exception to camelCase until now.

Comment: Eclipse seems to think so, `getqValue`.

Comment: You're running in a similar problem to the one I answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205006/why-does-jackson-2-not-recognize-the-first-capital-letter-if-the-leading-camel-c/30207335#30207335

Comment: damn. I got to say this was a really stupid decision by java bean.

Comment: well it actually makes sense. Otherwise java bean property names can't start with a capital letter + therefore can't handle acronyms like `URI`.