# Does Jackson deserialise the second character to lowercase for a property

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, fasterxml

We've defined a model in our service code as -

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class SomeData {

    public boolean tnAvailable;

    @NonNull
    public String sTempChange;

    public boolean isTnAvailable() {
       return faAvailable;
    }

    public void setTnAvailable(boolean faAvailable) {
        this.faAvailable = faAvailable;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getSTempChange() {
        return sTempChange;
    }

    public void setSTempChange(@Nonnull String sTempChange) {
        this.sTempChange = sTempChange;
    }

}
```

When the api including the above model in response is queried , we get the response as -

```
"someData": {
    "tnAvailable": true,
    "stempChange": "trial_001"
}
```

What surprised us was the `stempChange`(notice lowercase `t`) instead of `sTempChange` in the attributes of the response.

Suspecting the cause to be Jackson *com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:**2.5.2*** while serializing and deserializing of the objects during API calls since we do not alter the attribute using any other getter-setter ot wrapper. 
Why would this so happen and is serialization/deserialization the correct direction to look for this?

***Edit*** - From the comment by @Windle, trying to explain what's different here. I re-iterate *"The question though there relates pretty much to the same situation. Yet I 'm looking forward to the reason's for such implementation and documentation in fasterxml as well."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Jackson 2 not recognize the first capital letter if the leading camel case word is only a single letter long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205006/why-does-jackson-2-not-recognize-the-first-capital-letter-if-the-leading-camel-c) - that one has a [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30207335/298278) though =)

Comment: @Windle The question though there relates pretty much to the same situation. Yet I 'm looking forward to the reason's for such implementation and documentation in fasterxml as well.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question describes the reason in the very first sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handling of multiple leading capital letters in getters/setters (like "getURL()", or "getFName()"). 
By default, Jackson will simply lower-case ALL leading upper-case letters, giving "url" and "fname".
But if you enable **MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING** (added in Jackson 2.5), it will follow what Java Bean naming convention would do, which is only lower-case a single upper-case leading letter; if multiple found, do nothing.
That would result in properties "URL" and "FName".

Comment: *will simply lower-case ALL leading upper-case letters*... the question is about `sTempChange` single leading lower case character followed by an upper case character.

Comment: From the question itself, **What surprised us was the stempChange(notice lowercase t) instead of sTempChange in the attributes of the response**

Comment: @nullpointer It goes by your getter/setter. Which has been declared as **getSTempChange**

Comment: How is this an accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah it looks like it's getting confused on the method name. You can force the serialized name with the @JsonGetter annotation

```
@JsonGetter("sTempChange")
public String getSTempChange() {
    return sTempChange;
}
```

Comment: I know I can force it. More keen to know what confuses it.

Answer (score 3):

When I first tried out your `SomeData` class and serialized it I got the following results:

```
{"tnAvailable":true,"sTempChange":"trial_000","stempChange":"trial_000"}
```

This means that jackson doesn't match your getters/setters with the sTempChange property and they are treated as different properties. After adding the following configuration for my mapper I was able to reproduce your case:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

Now the reason for your error is because Jackson uses its own implementation of bean utilities (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.BeanUtil`) which is used when a class is processed for fields, getters and setters (done by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector`) when an instance is serialized/deserialized. Methods of interests are `okNameForGetter` and `okNameForSetter`. In those methods there are 2 other methods used depending on the `MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING` (it is passed in the `stdNaming` argument in all methods). The two methods are used in the following manner:

```
return stdNaming
                ? stdManglePropertyName(name, prefix.length())
                : legacyManglePropertyName(name, prefix.length());
```

The `stdManglePropertyName` follows the Java Beans specification in section 8.8 and the `legacyManglePropertyName` does not and is used in versions prior to 2.5 of Jackson.

*Now after running your getter and setter method names through this methods, however you set `MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING`, your getter/setter for `sTempChange` property is wrongly named. It should be `getsTempChange` (lowercase 's') and `getsTempChange` (again lowercase 's') to correctly serialize and deserialize the instances of `SomeData` class.*

Finally here is some code for testing:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class Test {

static class SomeData {

    public boolean tnAvailable;

    public String sTempChange;

    public String getsTempChange() {
        return sTempChange;
    }

    public void setsTempChange(String sTempChange) {
        this.sTempChange = sTempChange;
    }

    public boolean isTnAvailable() {
        return tnAvailable;
    }

    public void setTnAvailable(boolean tnAvailable) {
        this.tnAvailable = tnAvailable;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

//  objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING, true);

    SomeData someData = new SomeData();
    someData.setsTempChange("trial_000");
    someData.setTnAvailable(true);

//  objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
//  objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
//  objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
//  objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

    try {
        System.out.println("Serialize: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someData));

        String json = "{ \"tnAvailable\": false, \"sTempChange\": \"trial_001\" }";

        SomeData anotherData = objectMapper.readValue(json, SomeData.class);

        System.out.println("Deserialize: " + anotherData.isTnAvailable() + ", " + anotherData.getsTempChange());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: so what to do ?