# Spring converts attribute name to lowercase in JSON serialization

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin

I have this nested class

```
data class UI(
val xPosition: Int,
val yPosition: Int
)
```

When the Object gets serialized through the @RestController I receive *all lowercase* on the HTTP endpoint (last line is the interesting one):

```
{"id":"c8a7b735-b407-4dae-9a41-a470f7596895",
"isActive":false,
"title":"First Sample",
"description":{"shortDescription":"...","longDescription":"...","additionalNotes":"..."},
"endDate":"2021-01-07","priority":0,
"ui":{"xposition":0,"yposition":0}}]   <<<<<< see here
```

I copy the data into a MongoDB document. There it correctly states

```
ui:
xPosition: 0
yPosition: 0
```

What is going on here? I cannot get the Spring RestController to return the second letter as uppercase. This destroys the consumption and update of the data in the attached UI :(

Comment: Are you using Jackson to handle the JSON convertion?

Comment: Yes! It's the default in Spring

Comment: @nykon Hi, have you found any solution to the above problem?

Comment: @RajKhot I renamed my variables to lowercase

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205006/why-does-jackson-2-not-recognize-the-first-capital-letter-if-the-leading-camel-c

Answer (score 2):

For Java restrictions, the first 2 letters of a Json must be lowercase; I guess the only solution is to work with your variables as:

```
val xposition: Int,
val yposition: Int
```