# spring boot objectMapper ignores second uppercase letter

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, objectmapper

I'm using **Spring Boot 2.7.15**
And objectMapper that I use was created by `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`(spring-web:5.3.29).

I tried `objectMapper.writeValueAsString` with below class

```
data class SomeClass(
  val oAuthClientType: String,
  // ...
)
```

But result was like below

```
{"oauthClientType": "SOME_TYPE"}
```

Why second letter `A` upper case was ignored?
Is this bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Jackson 2 not recognize the first capital letter if the leading camel case word is only a single letter long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205006/why-does-jackson-2-not-recognize-the-first-capital-letter-if-the-leading-camel-c)

Comment: Also look at [this](http://futuretask.blogspot.com/2005/01/java-tip-6-dont-capitalize-first-two.html) and [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/92)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of being a bug, Jackson's ObjectMapper's default naming scheme is what is causing the behavior you are seeing. Jackson by default use the PropertyNamingStrategy naming scheme.SNAKE_CASE, which changes camelCase (or PascalCase) property names to snake_case. Snake_case converts uppercase characters to lowercase and uses underscores to separate words.

Because the second uppercase "A" is being changed to a lowercase "a" in your case and the word is not separated by an underscore, the property oAuthClientType is being converted to "oauthClientType".

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

// Create a custom ObjectMapper with the desired naming strategy
ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
    .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE) // Use LOWER_CAMEL_CASE
    .build();
```

When serializing to JSON using this option, the property name oAuthClientType will be kept exactly as-is.

Make sure your application's naming strategy adheres to your preferred name convention because changing it will have an impact on how all properties in your JSON objects are serialized.

Comment: Does it work and doesn't affect other behavior?